# What does "return to the well" mean in these sentences?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms, metaphors

Context 1: "I remember pa's hand in mine. Grasping and shaking for what felt like a thousand years...before he finally let go. His spirit released, allowing me brief communion before **returning to the well**."

Text was taken from comic "Seven to Eternity". Here's a [link](https://readcomiconline.to/Comic/Seven-To-Eternity/Issue-1?id=89544#18) where you can find the page with this text. As you'll see on the following pages there's no well with water. So I think that "returning to the well" can be some kind of metaphor or idiom. I have tried to search some information about this phrase and found [this](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?t=18761). But there is described only "go to the well with". I don't know if the meaning of this term ("go to the well") fits the meaning of my expression ("returning to the well").

And context 2: "We take solace that we **return him to the well**, true to himself". A link to the page [here](https://readcomiconline.to/Comic/Seven-To-Eternity/Issue-1?id=89544#19).

I can suggest that "the well" may be some magic limbo in the world of this comic. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard "return to the well" used in this way before.

I would assume you're right that "the well" is some fictional place or state of being that is specific to the lore of the comic's world.

I will note that "return to the well" *is* a common metaphorical idiom in English, meaning roughly "try to again use that resource".
e.g.
The author had great success with the "hero kid" trope, so it was tempting to keep returning to that well instead of writing adult characters.